# rsync multiple directories with quoted paths

Tags: bash, quotes, rsync, filepath

I am trying to rsync multiple directories in a single call inside of a bash script and am running into trouble with the syntax for quoting the paths.

Here is what I am trying:

```
backuppath='/path/to/backup/folders/'
declare -a backupitems=('folder1' 'folder2')
backupitems=(${backupitems[@]/#/\"$backuppath})
backupitems=(${backupitems[@]/%/\"})
backup=${backupitems[@]}

rsync ${backup} /path/to/destination
```

I get a link_stat error saying no such file or directory for `"/path/to/current/directory"/path/to/backup/folders/folder1""` and then the same error for folder2.  So it seems like it is generating the quoted path like I want it to, but rsync is interpreting the paths as relative and adding on the path to the current directory at the front.  rsync works correctly if I do

```
backuppath='path/to/backup/folders/folder1'
rsync "${backuppath}" /path/to/destination
```

putting the quotes into the rsync command, but I can't do this with multiple folders within one variable because it treats the multiple directories as a long single path.  I got the script to work using the second method by looping over the folders and calling rsync on each one, but this method is slightly more awkward because of the way other parts of the script handle the folders so I would like to get the first method to work if there is a quick fix.

**Edit:**

For the top version above, with no spaces in any of the directory names, I see the following command using `set -vx`: 
    rsync '"/path/to/backup/folders/folder1"' '"/path/to/backup/folders/folder2"' /path/to/destination

and I get the following error message:

```
rsync: link_stat "/path/to/current/directory/"/path/to/backup/folders/folder1"" failed: No such file or directory (2)
```

If I use the version suggested by @kdubs, then everything works when there are no spaces in the paths.

When there are spaces in the path, kdubs version results in the command:

rsync /path/to/back up/folders/folder1 /path/to/back up/folders/folder2 /path/to/destination

and the errors:

```
rsync: link_stat "/path/to/back" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: link_stat "/path/to/back up/up/folder1" failed: No such file or directory (2)
```

My first version needs an additional tweak to work with spaces because expanding the array with [@] and creating a new array by enclosing the expansion with () causes the spaces in the path to break up the path into multiple array elements (see Tonin's answer below).

Comment: good question, appreciate sample code. BUT.. will be much easier to diagnose your problem with the actual error messages inserted and formatted as code. Also try wrapping your call to rsync with `set -vx; rsync ... ; set +vx`. Good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Embedding quotes in your variables doesn't do anything useful. The best way to do this sort of thing is to put double-quotes around your variables when expanding them, and expand arrays as `"${arrayname[@]}"` -- that way bash will treat each element of the array as a separate word, even if they contain spaces or other shell metacharacters. The tricky thing is prefixing each element of the array with $backuppath, but you have the right approach to that (other than putting quotes around it, rather than in the value):

```
backuppath='/path/with spaces/'
backupitems=('folder 1' 'folder 2')   # declare -a is optional
backupitempaths=("${backupitems[@]/#/$backuppath}")

rsync "${backupitempaths[@]}" /path/to/destination
```

Comment: Definitely the best answer! The message is: _Use more quotes_! `+1`

Comment: Thanks!  This answer is closer to what I was originally looking for -- the right syntax to use when combining arrays, spaces, and quotation marks.

Answer (score 1):

The issue in your script lies in the way bash defines the elements of an array.  Elements are separated by spaces.  So when you re-assign the modified array elements back to the array, you're actually creating more elements than you had in the first place.  You can see that by adding an `echo ${#backupitems[@]}` after the array declaration and each assignment.

And at the end, when you flatten the array in the `$backup` variable, bash is even worsening the situation by making rsync believe it's given relative paths.

To solve this, I'll use the following script which works with spaces in file names (or anywhere in the path):

```
backuppath='/path/to/backup/folders/'
declare -a backupitems=('folder 1' 'folder 2')
PIFS=$IFS
# prevents creating new elements from the original array
IFS=''
backupitems=(${backupitems[@]/#/$backuppath})

rsync ${backupitems[@]} /path/to/destination
IFS=$PIFS
```

The script redeclares the `IFS` variable which changes bash behavior regarding records separators when creating an array.  There is a slight difference from your script though, in that the `$backup` variable cannot be used anymore, otherwise you'll flatten the array before actually putting it to use.  Let's hope it was not a requirement.

Comment: Yes, that works, thanks!  The backup variable is not important.  One note about your code: when I tested it, it seemed like it was okay to put `IFS=PIFS` before the `rsync` command (the IFS change does not seem to be needed in the `rsync` call).  backupitems is defined several lines before the `rsync` call in the script.  It seems like I don't need to hang on to the modified IFS through that code.

Comment: don't you need to save the IFS by using $IFS ? and restore it with $PIFS

Comment: @ws_e_c421 I'm not sure the IFS can be restored before calling rsync.  On my machine (bash 3.2.48 on OSX 10.8) rsync call fails if I restore it before.  But your mileage may vary...

Comment: @kdubs There was 2 typos on the IFS variable in my example, I fixed them, thanks.

Comment: Playing with `IFS` in this case is useless and shows that you don't really understand the role of double quotes in bash. Please see (and use!) Gordon Davisson's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of those quotes:

```
backuppath='/path/to/backup/folders/'
declare -a backupitems=('folder1' 'folder2')
backupitems=(${backupitems[@]/#/$backuppath})
backup=${backupitems[@]}

rsync ${backup} /path/to/destination
```

Comment: Hmm, sorry, I made the sample code a little too generic.  This works for the paths in the example, but not for paths that contain spaces in them like `/path/to/back up/folders/` -- that's the motivation for using the quotation marks.

Comment: ah. let me think about that then.

Comment: Don't get rid of quotes. Actually, _use more quotes_!

Comment: if the original question had mentioned spaces I would agree with you, but since it didn't would you remove the down vote.